# Ошибка WordPress при добавлении изображения в медиабиблиотеку

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите как исправить вот такую ошибку - **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /home/host1323541/beertastingvrn.ru/htdocs/www/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-imagick.php on line 354**

Comment: Для начала перевести текст ошибки, а не сразу постить на so. Скрипту 60 секунд не хватает для выполнения задачи.

Comment: Сменить хостинг на нормальный

Comment: @ilyaplot переводил и пробовал самостоятельно. Не получилось. Посему и спросил здесь.

Answer (score 1):

Вставь в начало скрипта вот это, позволит выполняться ему 120 секунд

```
ini_set('set_time_limit', 120)
```

Comment: уже вставлял - не помогло.

Comment: @anst-foto а "Maximum execution time of " c 60 до 120 сменилось? А то возможно хост запретил менять настройки php_ini

Comment: нет, не сменилось. Видимо хостер запретил.